# i want to check different array position in my Linq query

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am trying to count no of leaves condition **year** and **month** here is my LINQ query-

```
  leaves = ( from x in obj.Result
            where  (Int64.Parse(x.status) == 1 && 
                  ((x.start_date.Month == month && 
                    x.start_date.Year == selectedyear) && 
                   (x.end_date.Year == selectedyear || x.end_date.Month == month)))
          orderby x.user_id
           select x).ToList();
```

and I am getting a perfect result but now my start_date and end_date becomes 
the array of dates, in that array multiple leaves dates are stored

now I want to check my all record within that array condition year and month

here is my model example

```
  public DateTime start_date { get; set; }
        public DateTime end_date { get; set; }

        public List<string> Leaves_Date { get; set; }
```

and here also leaves_Date would be a string  so someone has an idea that how can I set array in my LINQ query

Comment: is this to be fullfilled on a database query, or is everything in memory?

Comment: fullfilled in database query

Comment: then how does your model look in the array case? just DateTime[] ? can this even be mapped?

Comment: i cant understand what you want to say

Comment: Your model does not have any arrays ... depending on your ORM (e.g. Entity Framework) it might not even be possible to have array fields... please provide your model/entity class and its corresponding mapping to your DB

Comment: i have list of leaves date i want to check that array with my month and year